# SetFocus with Firemonkey, on a dynamic created TEdit from StyleBook

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I have a custom styled TListBoxItem with a hidden TEdit component. When I select an item in my listbox, then I set the TEdit to visible:

```
importFiles.Selected.StylesData['nameEdit.visible'] := TRUE;
```

But i have a problem, how I could set the focus for the TEdit?
Normally, I do that this way:

```
Edit1.SetFocus();
```

Any ideas, how i could set the focus on the TEdit?

Comment: FireMonkey controls, including TEdit, have a [SetFocus method.](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.SetFocus)  What goes wrong when using it?  I assume something does, since the method you usually use exists. You need to give us details, we can't psychically debug (often, anyway.) One thing is that CanFocus has to be true, and if it isn't (check in the debugger) I'd suggest you step into what CanFocus is checking and find out what condition isn't met - probably (guessing) Visible or Enabled or something similar with its Parent.

Comment: @DavidM I guess the issue is that Holger does not have a reference to the control at hand. Look at how he made the control visible.

Comment: In that case, maybe FindComponent ([example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE4/en/FindComponent_(Delphi)), [reference](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Classes.TComponent.FindComponent)) would do the trick, if he knows the edit box owner - presumably the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use FindStyleResource to access the TEdit from the style:

```
procedure Form1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var O: TFMXObject;
begin
  if Assigned(ImportFiles.Selected) then
  begin
    O := TFMXObject(ImportFiles.Selected).FindStyleResource('NameEdit');
    if O is TEdit then
    begin
      TEdit(O).Visible := True;
      TEdit(O).SetFocus;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Hi Mike, much thanks for your help and instruction! Now i understand that i must handle my edit as an object to set the focus. Now it works perfect. Only: TEdit(O).Visible; must be: TEdit(O).Visible := True;
Best regards
Holger